# Calculate area and perimeter

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, area

I need 2 ways to calculate the area and perimeter of the shaded
 region

I've drawn it several times but the angles do not fit me

A) by elementary geometry

B) by integral calculation

[image: Figure to calculate]

Comment: Square root of 3 should make you imediately think of 60 or 30 degree angles.  The point of intersections of the circle is root(3), the radius 2 s the horizontal displacement is, by pythagorean thereom, 1.  So the angle from intersection, to center of circle, to horizontal line, is 60 degrees.  You can calculate the area by subtracting areas of triangles for semi circles.  You can find it be calculus on the spanned angle of 60 degrees.

Comment: What do you mean "the angles do not fit me"? As the comment and answer so far show, the angles are pretty easy. Just what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

By drawing a reasonable amount of auxiliary lines and circles it is pretty clear the area of the shaded region equals the area of an equilateral triangle with side length $2$, hence the wanted area is $\color{red}{\sqrt{3}}$.

With an integral:

$$ A = 2\int_{-2}^{1}\left|\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{4-x^2}\right|\,dx = \color{red}{\sqrt{3}}. $$

Comment: Thanks, the limits of the integral go from -2 to 1, was taken as 0, the midpoint of the base of the rectangle?

Comment: @SusyDiaz: exactly, I took the midpoint of $AD$ as the origin of the $xy$ plane.

Comment: How to calculate the perimeter using integral calculus?

Comment: @SusyDiaz: if $f(x)$ is a differentiable function on $[a,b]$, the length of the graph is given by $$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let $E$ and $F$ be  the intersections of the two semi-circles ($E$ on the left and $F$ on the right) and let $M$ be the midpoint of $AD$. Then the triangles $\triangle AEM$,  $\triangle EFM$, and  $\triangle FDM$ are all equilateral with sides of length $2$.

Comment: M will not be M's the midpoint of AD?

Comment: @Susy Diaz Yes, you are right.

Comment: thanks ....The problem was solved by me